# Which of the following are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[-1,1]×[-1,1]$, $A=\{(x,y)∈X: x^2+y^2 =1\}$, $B=\{(x,y)∈X:|x|+|y|=1\}$, $C=\{(x,y)∈X: xy=0\}$ and $D=\{(x,y)∈X: x=±y\}$. Then

A. A is homeomorphic to B
B. B is homeomorphic to C
C. C is homeomorphic to D
D. D is homeomorphic to A

i think Option A is true can any one help what about other options...thank u for your time

Answer (score 2):

C is also true... the space $C = \{(x,y)\in X| xy=0 \} = \{(x,0) | x\in [-1,1]\}\cup\{(0,y)|y\in[-1,1]\}$.

define $f : C\rightarrow D$ s.t $(x,0)\mapsto(x,x)$ and $(0,y)\mapsto(y,-y)$

check that it is a homeomorphism.

and the other two options are not true...If you assume they are homemorphism and if you remove the point $(0,0)$ from $C$ or $D$ then the space become disconnected on the other hand the if you remove the image of $(0,0)$ from $A$ or $B$ the space still remain connected. SO that is a contradiction.If you know a little bit about fundamental group...then also you can prove this thing in the following way that $C$ and $D$ is simple connected (contractible) but A and B are not.

Answer (score 0):

I think $C)$ is true also while $B)$, and $D)$ are false since removing a point in $X$ still leaves $X$ a connected set but not so for sets $C$ or $D$ if the origin is removed.

Comment: hi...thanks Oc-Sansoo,,but can u explain briefly..If u don't mind i am poor in homeomorphic

Comment: @sureshp: OC-Sansoo is suggesting you prove (and use) the following theorem: "If $f:A\to B$ a homeomorphism, then $A-\{p\}$ and $B-\{f(p)\}$ are homeomorphic." Can you see how to use this? Can you see how to prove this?

Comment: thanks i got it..thanks for your time